# glGenBuffers is NULL giving a 0x0000000 access violation when using glew

Tags: windows, opengl, access-violation

> I have visual studio c++ express and a NVIDIA GeForce 7900 GS. I'm using glew to get at the openGL extensions. Calling glGenBuffers crashes as its a NULL pointer tho. I have an open GL context before I make the call ( wglGetCurrentContext() != NULL ). I'm calling glewInit() before the call. glewGetString( GLEW_VERSION ) is returning GLEW_VERSION_1_5. What am I doing wrong ? Is the card too old ? Is it the driver ?

Comment: Are you passing a NULL pointer into glGenBuffers?

Comment: no absolutely not -> Gluint vbo; glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );

Comment: can you check if the function pointer to glGenBuffers is zero?

Answer (score 5):

Remember to make a `glewInit()` call in your code so that you get valid pointers to GL functions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it would be difficult to tell, but what you are attempting to do seems like it could be helped a lot by using [GLee](http://www.elf-stone.com/glee.php).  It is designed to load all current extensions and you have the ability to check what is supported, e.g. :

```
#include <gl\GLee.h>          // (no need to link to gl.h) 

...

if (GLEE_ARB_multitexture)    //is multitexture support available?
{
  glMultiTexCoord2fARB(...);  //safe to use multitexture
}
else
{
 //fallback
}
```

The above was shamelessly copy/pasted from the [GLee site](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/), but it displays the functionality I'm trying to showcase.

Comment: But I'm using glew which surely should suffice ?

Comment: @Mark: Never used glew, so I couldn't say for sure.  I was just offering up GLee as an alternative, as it has worked *very* well for me.  Some people who seem to have problems with glew don't have them with GLee (http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=154581).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call glewInit() post having a valid context. And that would be, in the world of glew, after you've called glfwMakeContextCurrent(myWindow);

Answer (score 0):

I have actually run into this problem with GLEW. For me, it was nullifying the function pointer for glGenerateMipmap. I fixed it by simply restoring the pointer to the appropriate function. This is my example in Linux:

```
glGenerateMipmap = (void(*)(GLenum))
    glXGetProcAddressARB((GLubyte*)"glGenerateMipmap");
```

There is a WGL equivalent for glXGetProcAddress; I just don't remember the name off the top of my head. Try manually restoring the functions using this method. If you come across *many* functions that are null, something is definitely wrong in your setup process. The only other functions I recall having to restore were glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray, and glDeleteVertexArrays. If your glGenBuffers is null, odds are that glBindBuffer and glDeleteBuffers are null as well. :(

Comment: wglGetProcAddress is the name.

Answer (score 0):

Test if the desired extension is actually supported by checking the string returned by glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS); if it's not there you know what's causing your problems.

Comment: One doesn't really know anything about the root cause, on doing that. One only knows that it's not enumerated.